# what is wrong this react js example

Tags: reactjs, reactive-programming

```
<script type="text/babel">
 var data = [
{id: 1, author: "Qamar", text: "This is one comment"},
{id: 2, author: "Aftab", text: "This is *another* comment"}
];

var CommentList = React.createClass({
render: function() {
var commentNodes = this.props.data.map(function(comment) {
return (
<Comment author={comment.author} key={comment.id}>
    {comment.text}
</Comment>
);
});
return (
<div className="commentList">
   {commentNodes}
</div>
);
}
});
```

ReactDOM.render(,document.getElementById('example'));

what is wrong this example .. when add {customNodes} inside Comment list  this is crash .

Answer (score 1):

As I see in your example there is no definition for `Comment` component

```
var Comment = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>
      <p>{ this.props.children }</p>
      <p>{ this.props.author }</p>
    </div>;
  }
});
```

also to `ReactDOM.render` you should pass React Component as a first argument

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <CommentList data={ data } />,
  document.getElementById('example')
);
```

[`Example`](https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/28263/)